# Neo4j MERGE relationships with properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm Neo4j noob and I'm trying to create unique relationship between two nodes depending on relationship properties.

Let's say we have `node A` and `node B`. I would like to create a new `relationship R` between A and B, if `R.since = 1` or `R.since IS NULL`. Otherwise I want to get an existing relationship.

I tried to do it like this:

```
MATCH (n:Crew { name: "Neo" }),(m:Matrix { name: "Agent Smith" })
MERGE (n)-[r:CATCH]->(m)
ON CREATE SET r.since = 1
WITH r WHERE r.since IS NULL OR r.since = 1 AND r.source = "ab"
RETURN r
```

but query returns nothing.

Comment: You're probably missing the `source` property on the relationship. If you remove the AND clause, you should get a result.

Answer (score 1):

Better to try with this code:

```
MATCH (n:Crew),(m:Matrix) WHERE n.name="Neo" and m.name="Agent Smith"
MERGE (n)-[r:CATCH]->(m)
ON CREATE SET r.since = 1
WITH r WHERE r.since IS NULL OR r.since = 1 AND r.source = "ab"
RETURN r
```